# javascript setting objects equal

Tags: javascript

this is working the way I want, however I am a bit confused why it works.

I have two objects.
set temp object equal to  object A and manipulate temp object.
Object A is affected.

set temp object equal to Object B (why aren't all three objects equal now?)
I manipulate temp object.
Object A is not affected.

```js
var tempObject = {};
var objectA = {A: 1};
var objectB = {A: 3};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    tempObject = objectA; 
    add(tempObject);
    console.log(objectA);
    tempObject = objectB;
    add(tempObject);
    console.log(objectA);  
    
   function add(arr){
     arr.A += 1;
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `tempObject` to `objectB`, it ceases being a reference to`objectA` and now refers to `objectB`. Thus, when you make changes to `tempObject`, `objectA` is not affected, but `objectB` is.

Answer (score 5):

When you deal with objects in JavaScript, it's always by-reference. It's kind of analogous to pointers in C/C++.

When you set `tempObject` to `objectA`, you are basically saying "tempObject now points to the same object as objectA". So, if you change a property of one, you change both.

When you then set `tempObject` to `objectB`, you are saying "tempObject now points to the same object as objectB". You aren't changing any of the objects with this, just which object `tempObject` is pointing to.